# Putting isCancelled Property in an NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, cocoa

So, I am using the `addOperationWithBlock^{}`method of the NSOperationQueue and I want to put the fine grained `isCancelled` property check at points in the operation code. How do I get the instance of the operation that will run while in this block?

For example, this is my code snippet:

```
[operationQueueInstance addOperationWithBlock:^{
    if (!???.isCancelled){
        NSlog(@"Instruction 1");
    }
    if (!???.isCancelled){
        NSlog(@"Instruction 2");
    }

    NSlog(@"Instruction 3");
 }];
```

How do I get the instance of the operation this block would run in so that I can evaluate the `isCancelled` property for the instructions?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apple docs:

> You should not attempt to get a reference to the newly created
>   operation object or divine its type information.

You could instantiate a [NSBlockOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSBlockOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) and assign it to a variable to keep an explicit reference instead.

`addOperationWithBlock` seems to be a shortcut for whenever you don't need a reference to the operation object.

Make sure to mark your block operation with the `__block` storage qualifier to avoid retain cycles.

Comment: In other words you might want to create an NSOperation subclass to do the work.